# Convert Elastic Search Results to Laravel 5 Collection

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5

I am just starting to use Elastic Search ([link](https://www.elastic.co/)) to handle all my search functionality in Laravel 5. I am using Laravel 5 with MySQL for the datastore and "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~1.0" in my composer.json file, and then model observers to update the Elastic Search index each time there is a change to the model ([this article was very helpful for setting up Laravel observers](http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/integrating-elasticsearch-with-your-laravel-app/)).

I can successfully query my data and get the results I want, but I would like to convert the results back into a Laravel model collection so I can use Laravel's relationships to display more data in the search results view.

For example: I queried Elastic Search for a list of articles containing the word "cat" and received the typical response back with an array of hits. I would like to convert this array back into a Laravel collection of Articles so I can then use the Article's relationship to get and display all the associated Comments.

I'm aware that several Laravel packages exist which may claim to make this easier, but I will need to do some pretty complex searching/filtering and I would like to stick with the official [elasticsearch/elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) package, if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with elasticsearch, but I thought if I can help your brainstorm you may find the answer. If the elasticsearch returns an array of IDs you can use the elasticsearch results in something `Article::whereIn('id', $elasticsearch_ids)->with('comments')->get()` to retrieve a normal eloquent model. Of course this will also cause two additional queries to be run, so it's probably not ideal.

Comment: @Azeame, that would be a good solution except that it would lose the order/ranking of the collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719728/pagination-in-elasticsearch-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using a NoSQL database like ElasticSearch flies away then.

Maybe what you could do is store te latest updated comments for each article in ES but when you want to display only one Article, you go for the MySQL version.

The article model could look like tis.

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Lorem"
"comments" {
    {
        "id": 1
        "message": "First comment"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
        "message": "Second comment"
    }
}
}
```

Makes not muc sense to me to retrieve only id from ES to later grap te element from SQL

Comment: I wondered if this might be the case... I will probably go this route. I just like using the built-in Laravel relationships (and subsequent built-in Laravel functions) so much better :-)

Comment: Exactly, make an observer that fills elastic search with related models once created or updated, then you can get all data with 1 call.

Comment: I also suggest to go this way. For list - use ElasticSearch. For displaying single item - go for eloquent version with all the relationships.
In my case - I store in ES index also counts for some relations (number of comments, number of child items etc...). This can be also useful in scoring ;)