# pagination in elasticsearch laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, pagination

I am using shift31/laravel-elasticsearch:~1.0. I want to implement pagination on my list page.

**Search code :**

```
   $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'product',
        'body' =>  [
                       'query'=>[
                                 'match'=>[
                                           'category'=>$category
                                          ]
                                 ]
                   ];
   ];
  $response = \Es::Search($params);
```

How to use pagination in above query ?

**Update :**

I used from and size in query but how to give pagination link in view page ? and how to update from by click on page ?

Comment: Have you looked in the docs at all? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Comment: OK thank you james. But how to give link on view page and what if i click on 2nd 3rd page of pagination link ? If i give 0 to 10 on first time.

Comment: Actually, have you tried paginating the results with the built in paginator. Try using `$response = \Es::Search($params)->paginate(10);` And then after passing this to your view using `$response->render()` to generate the paginator.

Comment: No I didn't use that. OK thanks let me try that one.

Comment: let me know how it goes

Comment: I am getting "Call to a member function paginate() on array" if i use Es::Search($params)->paginate(10);

Comment: any update on this post ? I am still not getting right thing. please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in repository

```
 $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'product',
          'size' = $per_page;
          'from' = $from;
        'body' =>  [
                       'query'=>[
                                 'match'=>[
                                           'category'=>$category
                                          ]
                                 ]
                   ];
   ];

$response = \Es::Search($params);
 $access = $response['hits'];
        return $access;
```

i set $per_page and $from in controller

```
$per_page = $request->get('limit', 10);
    $from = ($request->get('page', 1) - 1) * $per_page;
    $access = $this->repository->Index($per_page, $from);

    $admin_exceptions = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $access['hits'],
            $access['total'],
            $per_page,
            Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
            ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);
 return view('adminexception.index', compact('admin_exceptions'))->withInput($request->all());
```

and now use render in in the views {{!!$admin_exceptions->render()!!}}

Comment: can please share you LengthAwarePaginator() function >?

Comment: Sorry, can you please share your LengthAwarePaginator() function ?

Comment: Are you using php and larvel?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.1

Comment: LengthAwarePaginator() is a prebuilt function in laravel 5.1 package.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;`
`use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`