# How to use pagination with scan search type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use this config to scan my index

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$params = [
    "search_type" => "scan",    // use search_type=scan
    "scroll" => "30s",          // how long between scroll requests. should be small!
    "size" => 50,               // how many results *per shard* you want back
    "index" => "my_index",
    "body" => [
        "query" => [
            "match_all" => []
        ]
    ]
];

$docs = $client->search($params);   // Execute the search
$scroll_id = $docs['_scroll_id'];   // The response will contain no results, just a _scroll_id

// Now we loop until the scroll "cursors" are exhausted
while (\true) {

    // Execute a Scroll request
    $response = $client->scroll([
            "scroll_id" => $scroll_id,  //...using our previously obtained _scroll_id
            "scroll" => "30s"           // and the same timeout window
        ]
    );

    // Check to see if we got any search hits from the scroll
    if (count($response['hits']['hits']) > 0) {
        // If yes, Do Work Here

        // Get new scroll_id
        // Must always refresh your _scroll_id!  It can change sometimes
        $scroll_id = $response['_scroll_id'];
    } else {
        // No results, scroll cursor is empty.  You've exported all the data
        break;
    }
}
```

but i want order this scan by id and select result from 10.000 to 11.000 (my index have 33.000 result). How can do it?

I use from and size in this search body but it don't work.

Comment: Can you explain the real use case behind this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using scan and scroll ,pagination works but data repeats in every page.so only use from to

click the link   [Here is the data for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719728/pagination-in-elasticsearch-laravel/35722033)

It retrieves only 10000 records in a index with pagination.After 10,000 documents its shows errror.so also search data inbetween two dates for better results.

example:

```
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['range']['meta.datetime']['gte'] = $startdate;
$params['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['range']['meta.datetime']['lte'] = $enddate;
```